# On post back focus changes to address bar in IE 11 rather than shifting to next control in the form.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a form which behaves very strange. I have a drop down list which dose post back on each selection changed and after selection is done, Adjacent to that a check box control is displayed and focus is set to check box. When the user checks for the first time the check box control gets checked(At this time when I press tab the focus shifts to next control within the form). After couple of post back same behavior is repeated and check box is displayed adjacent to drop down and focus is set. Now when the user tries to check the check box for the second time it doesn't  get checked. I don't the reason why?(At this time when I press the tab the focus shifts to address bar). However when I click on the form and check the check box it gets checked.(At this time when I press tab the focus gets shifted to next control in the form)

**My question is: How should I stop the next focus getting shifted to address bar after couple of post back?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, so I hope this is somewhat helpful. You could use JQuery to set the focus to an element of your choice when the page loads like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#myElement').focus();
    });
```